# How to access a csv field in script task

Tags: c#, ssis

I am new to SSIS, and need to rewrite an old DTS package into a new SSIS package. The package has a script task. As I understand, the task accesses individual records in a csv file:

DTSSource("column name")

I cannot figure out how this (getting a cell value) can be done in SSIS script task. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In SSIS world you don't need to use script task, use "Data Flow Task", it has Flat file source which is suitable for most CSV files.
If you need some very custom transformations (or source) you can use Script Component step inside "Data Flow Task".

Comment: Do you have Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row) ? I thought it should be the same independently of data source...

Comment: @Georgy Smirnov Thank you for your comment. But will using Data Flow Task help me access the cell value better than using Script Task?

Comment: @Nick Sorry, could you please clarify your question for me, as I have not enough experience to understand?

Comment: If by "Cell" you mean "column", you can either define columns manually in a File File Connection or if the first row if the CSV has the column names, you can use those.  Click on the "Columns" section  (where General/Columns/Advanced/Preview are in the Flat File Connection Manager Editor.)  At that point you can treat it like any other source or destination.

Comment: @Duston Thank you for your comment. The csv does have column names, but how can I use it from the script? Could you please give me a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're goal is to use a script to process every record, I'm guessing that your looking for a Script Component, as opposed to Script Task.  A Script Component is within a Data Flow Task and can be connected to the output of a Flat File Source.  This will contain the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method, which is called once for each row from the input.  If by cell value you're referring to a column, each column of a row can be accessed by name from the `Row` parameter.  For instance, to get the value of ColumnA (assuming this is a DT_STR column) in a C# Script Component, you would use

```
string columnA = Row.ColumnA;
```

Comment: Thank you again, it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to give the script access to the column on the input tab of the script component GUI

Comment: Thanks @KeithL, the columns that will be accessed need to be added as input columns, with the appropriate usage type selected and (optionally) a new output alias.

Comment: Thank both of you. It is now up and running! :)